# Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I know I can measure the execution time of a call to `sess.run()`, but is it possible to get a finer granularity and measure the execution time of individual operations?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is not yet a way to do this in the public release. We are aware that it's an important feature and we are working on it.

Comment: Is it possible that there is an update to this answer? Because https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/899 seems as if one could probably calculate the FLOPs for individual operations which could give insights into the execution time.

Answer (score 111):

I have used the [**`Timeline`** object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py) to get the time of execution for each node in the graph:

- you use a classic `sess.run()` but also specify the optional arguments `options` and `run_metadata`
- you then create a `Timeline` object with the `run_metadata.step_stats` data

---

Here is an example program that measures the performance of a matrix multiplication:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

x = tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])
y = tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])
res = tf.matmul(x, y)

# Run the graph with full trace option
with tf.Session() as sess:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(res, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)
```

---

You can then open Google Chrome, go to the page `chrome://tracing` and load the `timeline.json` file.
You should see something like:

[image: timeline]

Comment: Hi! I tried creating a Timeline for my Network training, but unfortunately doing it as you showed only produces a timeline for the last invocation of session.run. Is there a way to aggregate the timeline over all sessions?

Comment: Using TensorFlow 0.12.0-rc0, I found that I needed to make sure that libcupti.so/libcupti.dylib was in the library path in order for this to work. For me (on Mac), I added `/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib` to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` on Ubuntu

Comment: Why is there an add operator here?

Comment: Because when calling `tf.random_normal`, TensorFlow first create a random tensor with mean 0 and variance 1. It then multiplies by the standard deviation (1 here) and adds the mean (0 here).

Comment: My `.json` is around 1.7 GB and I'm unable to open it in Chrome. Is there any other way to open it like in tensorboard ?

Answer (score 23):

Since this is high up when googling for "Tensorflow Profiling", note that the current (late 2017, TensorFlow 1.4) way of getting the Timeline is using a [ProfilerHook](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook). This works with the MonitoredSessions in tf.Estimator where tf.RunOptions are not available.

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=...)
hook = tf.train.ProfilerHook(save_steps=10, output_dir='.')
estimator.train(input_fn=..., steps=..., hooks=[hook])
```

Answer (score 14):

You can extract this information using [runtime statistics](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz#runtime_statistics). You will need to do something like this (check the full example in the above-mentioned link):

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
sess.run(<values_you_want_to_execute>, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
your_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
```

---

Better than just printing it you can see it in tensorboard:

> Additionally, clicking on a node will display the exact total memory,
>   compute time, and tensor output sizes.

[image: [Example from link]

Comment: The link (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graph_viz#runtime_statistics) has been updated.

Answer (score 11):

To update this answer, we do have some functionality for CPU profiling, focused on inference. If you look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark you'll see a program you can run on a model to get per-op timings.

Comment: What about getting GPU benchmarks on raw Tensorflow operations?

Answer (score 2):

For the comments of *fat-lobyte* under *Olivier Moindrot*'s answer, if you want to gather the timeline over all sessions, you can change "`open('timeline.json', 'w')`" to "`open('timeline.json', 'a')`".

Answer (score 1):

As of Tensorflow 1.8, there's a really good example for using the `tf.profile.Profiler` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/Profiler).

Comment: The link is dead, is there an updated version ? (still for TF 1.x)

Answer (score 1):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: You can use `Profiling` in **`Keras Callback`**.

Code for that is :

```
log_dir="logs/profile/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 3)

model.fit(train_data,
          steps_per_epoch=20,
          epochs=5, 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

For more details on how to Profiling, refer this [Tensorboard Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras).

Answer (score 0):

This works with Tensorflow 2 (tested with TF 2.5 and 2.8):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.profiler.experimental.start(r'/path/to/logdir')
with tf.profiler.experimental.Trace("My cool model", _r=1):
    run_model_that_you_want_to_profile()
tf.profiler.experimental.stop()
```

Then you can see the trace in Tensorboard (`tensorboard --logdir /path/to/logdir`, then open http://localhost:6006/#profile in the browser).

Might also be useful:

- Guide: [Optimize TensorFlow performance using the Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler)
- [`tf.summary.trace_on()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/trace_on) (didn't try it myself)
- [This colab tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/docs/tensorboard_profiling_keras.ipynb) on using the Tensorboard profiler

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Recently released by Uber SBNet custom op library (http://www.github.com/uber/sbnet) has an implementation of cuda event based timers, which can be used in the following manner:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([input1, input2]):
    dt0 = sbnet_module.cuda_timer_start()
with tf.control_dependencies([dt0]):
    input1 = tf.identity(input1)
    input2 = tf.identity(input2)

### portion of subgraph to time goes in here

with tf.control_dependencies([result1, result2, dt0]):
    cuda_time = sbnet_module.cuda_timer_end(dt0)
with tf.control_dependencies([cuda_time]):
    result1 = tf.identity(result1)
    result2 = tf.identity(result2)

py_result1, py_result2, dt = session.run([result1, result2, cuda_time])
print "Milliseconds elapsed=", dt
```

Note that any portion of subgraph can be asynchronous you should be very careful with specifying all the input and output dependencies for the timer ops. Otherwise, the timer might get inserted into the graph out of order and you can get erroneous time. I found both the timeline and time.time() timing of very limited utility for profiling Tensorflow graphs. Also note that cuda_timer APIs will synchronize on the default stream, which is currently by design because TF uses multiple streams.

Having said this I personally recommend switching to PyTorch :) Development iteration is faster, code runs faster and everything is a lot less painful.

Another somewhat hacky and arcane approach to subtracting the overhead from tf.Session (which can be enormous) is to replicate the graph N times and run it for a variable N, solving for an equation of unknown fixed overhead. I.e. you'd measure around session.run() with N1=10 and N2=20 and you know that your time is t and overhead is x. So something like

```
N1*x+t = t1
N2*x+t = t2
```

Solve for x and t. Downside is this might require a lot of memory and is not necessarily accurate :) Also make sure that your inputs are completely different/random/independent otherwise TF will fold the entire subgraph and not run it N times... Have fun with TensorFlow :)

Comment: This example is lacking a complete set of variables or suggestion on how to create them.  When I clicked on the sbnet repo in Github, it appears to be 3-4 years stale anyway.