# how to get the time consumed to execute each node in tensorflow graph

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I can run through my tensorflow graph correctly, but the running time is longer than my expectation, so I'd like to know how to profile execution time for each node in the graph.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use fields recorded in [step_stats](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/step_stats.proto). [TimelineTest](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3c8780451007c27b69f10925d43d1f3501d94106/tensorflow/python/client/timeline_test.py) shows an example of how to get stats about execution.

Comment: encounter this error `ImportError: cannot import name timeline`, info about  my tensorflow package `v0.7.1/CPU`

Comment: The timeline code is only supported in the latest nightly builds or if you build from source. It will be in the 0.8 release.

Comment: thanks @mrry , I just download the latest build from `http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-matrix-cpu/TF_BUILD_CONTAINER_TYPE=CPU,TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON2,label=cpu-slave/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`, and install it with `pip install tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl `, but it failed with error `tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Just to check, are you running on Linux with Python 2.7?

Comment: @mrry very sorry for the mistake, I'm running on MacOS with Python 2.7.

Comment: Glad it's a simple fix! :)

Comment: @mrry  looks the interface of some functions changed in 0.8 release, need lots of fixes :(