# Tensorflow Timeline with SKFlow

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, skflow

The Tensorflow Timeline described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37774430/198401) is a method of profiling tensorflow runs using the Chrome tracing machinery. However to use it, seems to require setting options in the `Session.run()` call, e.g.:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(network, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
```

In SKFlow one usually doesn't have access to the actual `Session.run()` call. Instead, one calls `Estimator.fit()`, e.g. from the [landing page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn):

```
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target, steps=200, batch_size=32)
```

Is it possible to run SKFlow with the full trace option so Tensorflow Timeline can be used? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow contrib contains a [`ProfilerHook`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/hooks/README.md). Since it appears to have been added after 1.0 you may need to use a [nightly build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) or copy the class definition from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/hooks/python/training/profiler_hook.py).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with TensorFlow Timeline but you can probably look into using `SessionRunHook` (originally monitors in TF.Learn) to attach with the `tf.Session()`. Hope this helps.