# Performance of single segment operation vs multiple operations on segments

Tags: python, tensorflow

Since currently there is no easy way to profile TensorFlow operations ([Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/tensorflow-can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations)), can anyone help me understand the benefits of using segment operations (e.g. `segment_sum`) compared to using multiple operations on pre-segmented tensors? Would `segment_sum` be more efficient than using `dynamic_partition` or `gather` followed by multiple `reduce_sum`? Would `segment_sum` be equally parallelizable?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the SO question you link to with some information about CPU inference profiling tools we've recently released at:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark

Unfortunately the overall question is a lot harder to answer, since it depends on:

- Whether you're focused on training, or inference.
- If you're using a GPU, and if so what kind and how many.
- Whether you're running distributed.
- What your data looks like, and where the bottlenecks are.

What I usually end up doing is building small sub-graphs that are representative of the sort of ops I'm considering, and then timing how long they take on the sort of data I'll be feeding in. I know that isn't immediately helpful, since the experimentation can be time-consuming, but it is the best way to get an intuitive understanding of the optimal solution for your particular circumstances.

Comment: Just wondering why you mention training or inference as a factor? I'm just wondering about the properties of an operation and actually, I am not using TF for implementing CNNs (or other NNs). Regarding other points, can TF automatically parallelize an operation (or even a subgraph) on multiple GPUs? I though it cannot. Let's assume for the sake of this question that we are speaking of running each of the two cases on a single GPU (i.e. I am not going to compare the single op solution to multi-op solution distributed on multiple GPUs).