# TensorFlow profiling

Tags: profiling, tensorflow

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37774470/6618884) offered the way how to profile tensorflow code. In my case I launch tf.run in several threads in parallel. How I can use this technique to profile multithreading architecture? When I use global metadata and options they log only single thread.

Thanks!

Comment: Each run metadata profiles a single run call, if you have several.run calls in parallel, you could combine metadata info manually

Comment: If you are using tf.Estimator, ProfilerHook is the way to go. See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/ProfilerHook