# How to measure the time of sess.run() from TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

How to measure the time of execution of running a given task in the session?

```
sess.run(variables)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the python `time` package, as Tensorflow authors did in the [AlexNet Benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/alexnet/alexnet_benchmark.py#L171)

```
start_time = time.time()
_ = session.run(variables)
duration = time.time() - start_time
print(duration)
```