# Specify ops for profiling

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow) excellent example how to profile Tensorflow computation graph, but output is very clutter, there is way to specify which **op** to trace?

Comment: Not in core tensorflow, but you can get the raw information from run_metadata.step_stats, and filter it out yourself