# Understanding tensorflow profiling results

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow/37774470#37774470) shows how to profile tensorflow programs. I have used this tool to profile my program, a simple LSTM. And the results is shown as:

`/gpu:0/stream:all Compute(pid 5)`

[image: MatMul_AllCompute]

`/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 Compute(pid 3)`

[image: MatMul_GpuCompute]

My question :

a)what is the meaning of each row.

b)Especially what is the difference between `/gpu:0/stream:all Compute(pid 5)`  and `/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 Compute(pid 3)`.

c)Why their execution time are different, namely `0.072ms` and `0.094ms`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an update from one of the engineers:

The '/gpu:0/stream:*' timelsines are hardware tracing of CUDA kernel execution times.

The '/gpu:0' lines are the TF software device enqueueing the ops on the CUDA stream (usually takes almost zero time)

Comment: so, the number in `/gpu:0` line includes the gpu kernel launch time?