# Tensorflow profiling in TF2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to visualize the performance of tf.data.Datasets using TF2.0 (Beta). I found examples on how to use profiler in older versions of tensorflow. 
How is profiling done in TF2.0? I could use tf.compat.v1, but the procedure does not seem to be straight forward.

I want to measure memory consumption (device placement wise) and timeline.

Below examples explain profiling with TF1.x
[Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow/37774470#37774470)

[Understanding tensorflow profiling results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372542/understanding-tensorflow-profiling-results)

Comment: See [this new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71393541/857731) in one of the threads you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found solution to my question:
Using the trace_on and trace_export around my training step to get the profiler output, as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/graphs#graphs_of_tffunctions) 
[image: Example Profile]

Comment: Do you remember who you got the chrome tracing tool working? With the instructions I get a profiling output consisting of the regular TB `events.out.tfevents....` files, a similar named `events.out.*.profile-empty` and `plugins/profile/{timestamp}/local.trace`. The last one seems like the one I am looking for, however chrome won't load it into the tracing tool. Any help/hint would be appreciated!

Comment: @DavidS. the tracing tool is currently broken on chrome 80+. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3209#issuecomment-584292018

Comment: @DavidS. Sorry that I missed your message. I used chrome version 75.0.3770.100 and it worked fine. Profiling records a lot of information, I've seen that recording for too long or larger computations takes times to load on chrome. or sometimes hangs. Hope this helps!
Luke: Thanks for your hint.

Comment: The link in the answer went dead. Is there another version?

Comment: @MichaelLitvin Here is the link for TF v2.8.0: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/trace_on
further, you can find in the relevant api_docs for your specific version as well.