# Difference between Profiling and Trace in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, profiling, tensorflow2.0

I was looking for a solution for Profiling in tensorflow. See [Tensorflow profiling in TF2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756028/tensorflow-profiling-in-tf2-0).

Since I could not find a solution for tensorflow2.0, I am using https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/summary/trace_on

As indicated in the documentation, it incurrs high memory overload, but between two given points in code, I am able to trace the runtime and memory.

What are the other differences between these methods(i.e, Profiler and Trace)?

Comment: Meanwhile, I found solution my profiling in TF2.0 Question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756028/tensorflow-profiling-in-tf2-0