# How to profile TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow

How can I profile TensorFlow models? I want at least to find ways to make the model faster, see how much GPU load I have, and how much GPU memory is consumed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to profile models. One way is a tensorboard. Here is a [comprehensive](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz) tutorial about it and here is a good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4).

> Additionally, clicking on a node will display the exact total memory,
>   compute time, and tensor output sizes.

[image]

---

Another way is tensorflow debugger, which also has [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger).