# Chrome tracing gives blank page when load JSON file from Tensorflow Timeline

Tags: python, json, google-chrome, tensorflow

I'm profiling a TensorFlow run using Timeline as is explained in this answer [Can I measure the execution time of individual operations with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow/37774470#37774470). My model contains a big number of parameters, so the generated json for each run is pretty big (about 400MB).

When I try to load the json into chrome://tracing, although, nothing shows up:
[image]

What can this be?

Comment: Have you tried doing in using [tensorboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43692312/1090562)?

Comment: @SalvadorDali is it possible to use Tensorboard for profiling? My problem right now is that my model is occupying too much GPU memory to the point that it gives an OOM error. So I am trying to find a way to see which variables are occupying so much memory.

Comment: yes, it is possible. Take a look at that answer and go through the tutorial to see what will you get. I remember that you can access the time of execution of each op and memory taken.

Comment: Do you try to only output timeline for each batch? I am wondering if that would help to reduce the size of timeline data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ended up finding out that chrome://tracing is unable to open files that are larger than about 300MB

Comment: My trace.json is 1 GB. Cannot be loaded either.

Comment: I had same problem when I used pytorch profiler with tensorboard. trace.json lager than 500MB was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch to https://ui.perfetto.dev/ if you are using the latest Chrome.