# Does chrome tracing work with Tensorflow estimators?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been using [chrome tracing with sessions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824) for a while now, however, I am now working with an estimator instead of a session.

Is it still possible to trace code with estimators? If so, how?

Comment: For tensorflow 1, Urs' answer here maybe answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293714/can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-individual-operations-with-tensorflow/37774470