# Iterator 40,000 times faster on CPU than GPU worker

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am comparing two training runs of a `tf.Estimator.Estimator` model fed by a `tf.data.Dataset` iterator. The training is handled by `tf.train_and_evaluate()`

When I look at the traces of a single training step I noticed that the GPU training is dominated by the `IteratorGetNext` call which takes 4.5 seconds. The same call when trained using cpus only takes only 100us. See the following photos of the traces:

## cpu training:

[image: cpu training]

## gpu training:

[image: gpu training]

What could be causing this, and how can I improve the speed of the GPUs `IteratorGetNext`?

Comment: I guess you have issues feeding the gpu. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715062/tensorflow-performance-bottleneck-on-iteratorgetnext

Comment: This would be my guess as well -- but is there any way of prefetching the data on the GPU memory?

Comment: I did send you a link. The guy answered with this official doc
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets

Comment: I've already implemented all of those suggestions -- but AFAIK these only improve the speed if the bottleneck is cpu compute, not communication time between gpu and cpu.

Comment: I would think the slowdown was due to cpu computer time were it not for the fact the CPU-only trained model was so fast, indicating that the cpu is more than capable of doing the pre-processing I put in the input pipeline.

Comment: Umm, I do not think anyone can extrapolate anything from your opening post.
There isnt any idea on how long your models takes to compute nor how big it is. I am not sure if those graphs are complete or a segment.

Comment: These indicate a single training step. The point is only to illustrate the relative speed of the same step `IteratorGetNext` on cpu vs gpu system.